# Plotting Incidence function of the SIR Model

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, modeling

I am working on the SIR model and I am trying to plot the incidence function on a specific time interval.

```
(*Given parameters*)\[Gamma] = 0.1;
\[Beta] = 0.41;
tMax = 90;
n = 10^6;

(*Define the force of infection (\[Lambda])*)
\[Lambda][t] := \[Beta] i[t]/n;

(*Define the system of differential equations*)
eqns = {s'[t] == -\[Lambda][t] s[t], 
   i'[t] == \[Lambda][t] s[t] - \[Gamma]*i[t], r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t],
    s[0] == 999999, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

(*Solve the system*)
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, tMax}];

(*Plot the solutions*)
Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], i[t], r[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tMax}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Infected", "Recovered"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

[image]
So far so simple.
But when I am trying to define and plot the incidence equation

```
(*Define the incidence function*)
incidence[t_] = Integrate[\[Lambda][t]*s[t], {t, 40, 50}];

(*Plot the incidence*)
Plot[incidence[t], {t, 0, tMax}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Incidence"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> "Incidence between t=40 and t=50"]
```

[image]

Could someone explain to me why I have the errors `Integrate::ilim` and `NIntegrate::itraw` and no plot?

Comment: Something is odd in your definition of incidence: how can incidence be a function of t, if t is also the integration variable and it spans a pre-determined range? Should perhaps the variable be a `tmax` or similar and the integration range be `{t, 40, tmax}` or something along those lines? Also, shouldn't you inject the results of NDSolve in the definition of incidence as well?

Comment: @MarcoB Oh! I got it.Τhanks a lot for the boost

Comment: `incidence[t_]` is not actually a function of `t` in your definition since it's just a dummy variable under `Integrate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works:

```
Clear[incidence]
incidence[tmax_] := NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol, {t, 40, tmax}]

Plot[incidence[t], {t, 40, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why
 `NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. (First@sol), {t, 40, tmax}]` looks different from `NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol, {t, 40, tmax}]` even though all `First` is doing is removing an extra curly around `sol` (there's only one element in `sol`)?

Comment: @ydd You need to use `First@sol` to get a correct answer, but someone else will have to explain why a list even seems to work at all.

Comment: @MichaelE2  ydd and Alan's question is why the two plots are difference. `Clear[incidence1, incidence2];
incidence1[tmax_] := 
  NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol, {t, 40, tmax}];
incidence2[tmax_] := 
  NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol[[1]], {t, 40, tmax}];
Plot[{incidence1[t], incidence2[t]}, {t, 40, 90}]`

Comment: And why if we replace `t` to another letter such `u`, then there are no such problem. `Clear[incidence1, incidence2]; 
incidence1[tmax_] := 
 NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol, {t, 40, tmax}]; 
incidence2[tmax_] := 
 NIntegrate[(λ[t]*s[t]) /. sol[[1]], {t, 40, 
   tmax}]; Plot[{incidence1[u], incidence2[u]}, {u, 40, 90}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, 
   Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[10], Opacity[.2], Automatic}}]`

Comment: @cvgmt Ah, I thought the "looks different" referred to the extra braces on the output of `incidence[]` output.  The reason is in part because `incidence[]` depends on a global parameter `t`, whose evaluation leaks sometimes. Better code: `incidence[tmax_?NumericQ] := Block[{t}, NIntegrate[(\[Lambda][t]*s[t]) /. sol, {t, 40, tmax}]]` -- But maybe it should be called a bug?

Comment: @Alan If you're asking why `NIntegrate[{f1, f2,...},...]` works, it's because it integrates each component separately. See docs, Scope > Basic Uses > "Vector- and tensor-valued functions". (The separately is not documented but is discussed somewhere on this site; but I can't find the Q&As, sorry.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the explanation. I hope I don't run into this kind of problem in the future, because it sounds like it would be very difficult to catch this "bug" (I guess it's more of a scope issue than a bug it sounds like) while debugging. I guess just using local variables fixes it, but I still do not have enough skills to always decide when to use local variables :-D

Comment: @ydd You're welcome. According to the docs, "NIntegrate has attribute HoldAll and effectively uses Block to localize variables." If that was true, we wouldn't need `Block[{t},...]` in my comment. That's why I suggested it was a bug.

Answer (score 5):

- Add an equation `incident'[t] == λ[t]*s[t], incident[0] == 0`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
γ = 0.1;
β = 0.41;
tMax = 90;
n = 10^6;
λ[t] := β i[t]/n;
eqns = {s'[t] == -λ[t] s[t], 
   i'[t] == λ[t] s[t] - γ*i[t], r'[t] == γ*i[t],
    incident'[t] == λ[t]*s[t], s[0] == 999999, i[0] == 1, 
   r[0] == 0, incident[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {s, i, r, incident}, {t, 0, tMax}];
Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], i[t], r[t], incident[t]} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, tMax}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Infected", "Recovered", "Incidence"},
  AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Directive@{Black, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

- And calculus on specific time interval like `40<=t<=50`

```
incident[50] - incident[40] /. sol[[1]]
```

> `569781.`

- When we  fixed the length of the interval to `10` and vary the endding point `b` of the inverval,the plot is

```
Plot[incident[b] - incident[b-10] /. sol[[1]], {b, 10, 90}]
```

[image]

- When we fixed the beginning point and endding point of the interval, the plot is

```
Plot[incident[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 40, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[incident[t + 10] - incident[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 90}]`

Comment: `Plot[incident[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 40, 50}]`.

Comment: Could you explain to me please why the first graph" your answer" and the second graph "first comment" are different? I am a bit confused

Comment: Understood that! I am confused because when I try my initial code + the following code I have different results


```inc[tmax_] := NIntegrate[{\[Lambda][t]*s[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]``` and ```Plot[inc[t], {t, 40, 50}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Incidence"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange] ``` and  ```inc[50] - inc[40] /. sol```

Comment: I think you shifted the incidence plot by 10. That is, incidence at t should be observed incidence over an interval, not projected incidence. See my earlier answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect (?) you are after something more like

```
Clear[incidence]
incidence[tmax_, dt_] := 
 NIntegrate[(\[Lambda][t]*s[t]) /. First@sol, {t, tmax - dt, tmax}]
Plot[incidence[t, 10], {t, 10, 90}]
```

[image]